# What design pattern do I use when I need to call a helper function before I create an object?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have a class `Motor`, which I use to provide me with various motor specifications.

I currently have the following methods as part of the `Motor` class:

```php
public function getIdFromModel($model)
{
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM ... WHERE model = ...";
    return process($sql);
}

public function getIdByFrame($size)
{
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM ... WHERE size = ...";
    return process($sql);
}
```

The above are supplementary functions used to get motor's `id` from database, when some other non-`id` parameter is known.  `id` is then used to create the actual motor.

Before I could do:

```php
$model = "ABC";
$motor = new Motor();

//retrieve ID
$id = $motor->getIdFromModel($model)

$motor-loadSpecs($id);
$motor = new Motor($id);
```

My problem shows up after I have changed the structure of my class to require knowledge of `id` at `Motor` creation time.  Now I need to do:

```php
$model = "ABC";

//retrieve ID
$id = $???->getIdFromModel($model)

$motor = new Motor($id);
```

**Question**

What structure/class/pattern/function do I use in place of `???` above?

I know that I can create a class just for the above two functions, but I feel there is a better answer/pattern for this and I wanted to ask.  I don't see a *meaning* for creating a class just for something-to-id methods.  I'd like to have some meaning.

Comment: Reflection ( i think ) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reflection-in-php--net-31408

Comment: I would recommend a [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) that returns the `$motor` entity instead of a getter setting with separate "hydrating-lite" methods. An object doesn't create itself, in my opinion. See also: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

Comment: Did you ever settle on any approach?

Comment: I removed the methods from the above class and put them as helper methods into my test suite.  Only the test suite was requiring the methods.  Hence, my approach was 'move offending methods elsewhere'.  Ideally though I would pick Factory Pattern, and inside it use methods like `idFromModel()`, `idFromFrame()`, and call it like `$motor = new Factory()->getMotorFromModel($model);` or `$motor = new Factory()->getMotorFromFrame($frame);` or `$motor = new Factory()->getMotorFromId($id);`

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use a Factory Patter for this. It could be a stand-alone function or a static class method depending on how you want to implement it.

http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd make them static functions, member of Motor.

```
public static function getIdFromModel($model)
{
  ..
}
```

Then you can call the function, without the need of an instance.

```
$id = Motor::getIdFromModel($model)
```

Comment: "What structure/class/pattern/function do I use in place of ??? above?"
I know it's not a design pattern, but I've answered your question imho.

Comment: that works..  although I want to find these methods a more permanent home.   I see them as more *supporting* methods for the `Motor` class.  They are not essential to `Motor`, and I think it's best to have them removed from out of there.

Comment: OK, it wasn't completely clear to me from your question.
Good luck with the quest.

Answer (score 0):

Factory Method + supporting methods

**Usage:**

```
$id = 17;
$model = "ABC";
$frame = "T123";

$factory = new MotorFactory();

//instantiation via various pieces of data
$motor = $factory->fromId($id);
$motor = $factory->fromModel($model);
$motor = $factory->fromFrame($frame);
```

**Factory Method:**

```
class MotorFactory
{
    public function fromId($id)
    {
        return new Motor($id);
    }

    public function fromModel($model)
    {
        $id = $this->getIdFromModel($model);
        return $this->fromId($id);
    }

    public function fromFrame($frame)
    {
        $id = $this->getIdFromFrame($frame);
        return $this->fromId($id);
    }

    //supporting methods
    private function getIdFromModel($model)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM ... WHERE model = ...";
        return process($sql);
    }

    private function getIdFromFrame($size)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM ... WHERE size = ...";
        return process($sql);
    }
}
```